# How to insert images from JSON data with JQuery, using a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Trying to insert several images into a webpage from a JSON data provided to me. It looks like this:

```
"tvdb_id": 80379,
"tvrage_id": 8511,
"ended": false,
"images": {
  "poster": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/posters/34.66.jpg",
  "fanart": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/fanart/34.66.jpg",
  "banner": "http://slurm.trakt.us/images/banners/34.66.jpg"
},
```

Here is my code:

```
var sTvrageId = $("<p></p>").html("<b>TV RAGE ID: </b>" + data[key].tvrage_id);
var sEnded = $("<p></p>").html("<b>Ended: </b>" + data[key].ended);
var sImages = $("<img>").html((j=0, j < data[key].images.length, j++)data[key].images[j]);
```

However, no matter what variation I try on syntax for the loop, it won't insert the images. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should show us the code for the actual loop, not just the stuff inside it.

Comment: `images.length` is probably `0` because its not an array. You have to use the names of the attributes or cycle through the properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't iterate inside the `html()` method for one image tag and expect to get three images ?

```
var sTvrageId = $("<p />", {html: "<b>TV RAGE ID: </b>" + data[key].tvrage_id});
var sEnded    = $("<p />", {html: "<b>Ended: </b>" + data[key].ended});
var sImages   = $([]);

$.each(data[key].images, function(_, src) {
     sImages = sImages.add(
           $('<img />', {src : src});
     );
});
```